# What is the better way to Upload a picture

Tags: java, android, post, upload, ftp

I am writing an Android App.

I want to know whether it is better to upload a picture by `Http POST` or by using `ftp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend HTTP post because if too many people are uploading at once, then ftp might crash.

Answer (score 0):

use http post is the better way to do it

Answer (score 0):

use `MimeType` over `HTTP post`. that would be the best way